# Graphite carbon ceres maintenance

Tags: graphite

I'm using [Carbon Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) with the Ceres database backend. I am having difficulty in working out how to get the dedrag working in order to consolidate the slices.

I've tried the following but I get a rather strange error:

```
$ /opt/graphite/bin/ceres-maintenance --configdir=/opt/graphite/conf/carbon-daemons/example/ defrag
/opt/graphite/storage/ceres/ is not inside a CeresTree
```

does anyone have any insight? there appears to be very little on the web about this.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibles:

1. The default location of your data directory is specified by --root.  So, specify it.  That is, the one that might be /opt/datastore/ceres/  (or not).
2. If you're sure you're pointing to to the correct --root, make sure you're not missing the .ceres-tree directory (mkdir /opt/datastore/ceres/.ceres-tree/)

Put it all together with:

/opt/graphite/bin/ceres-maintenance --configdir=/opt/graphite/conf/carbon-daemons/example --root=/opt/datastore/ceres/

optionally, you can add --daemon and --logdir=/tmp/mydefrag.log